# Can you write an algorithm that can generalize another algorithm?

Tags: algorithms, halting-problem, incompleteness

Can you write an algorithm which can take in a given function/algorithm, and produce a distribution of generalizations of the function at hand? One such simple example of generalization might mean the generalization from the factorial function to the gamma function, or the generalization of the irrationals to the reals.

Is such an algorithm ultimately incomputable, and thus reducible to the Halting problem?

Comment: Please define what you want more precisely. The first generalization can be achieved by using linear functions between $n$ and $n+1$ (of course, it won't be a gamma function, but, again, you didn't define what "generalization" means). For the second generalization, since irrational numbers don't exist in computer representation, you don't need to do anything.

Comment: @Dimitry, yes, this question might need to be flagged as needing focus. I realize now that my question is generic and vague.

Comment: I think part of the problem may be that there are many statements that are a generalization of another, but many of them are uninteresting or trivial. Even worse, whether generalizations are interesting is more of a matter of opinion than a hard science. Therefore, asking for a reduction to the Halting problem may be the wrong question to ask.

Comment: As a side note, "incomputable and thus reducible to the Halting problem" greatly underestimates the sheer variety of undecidable problems. There are many [degrees of undecidability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_degree) strictly below that of the halting problem, many incomparable with it, and many strictly greater than it.